# Turn object key to array index and return a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was trying to solve this problem which I have an object that contains key-value pairs and looking for a way to assign each key to a specific index and return a new array. 
Please note: when the key is not found, the index should be assigned to 0 since it starts from 1 to 12, not at index 0.

```
var obj = {
  4: 7,
  6: 8,
  7: 6,
  8: 8,
  9: 3,
  10: 6,
  11: 4,
  12: 3
};
```

The result would be:

```
var output = [0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 8, 6, 8, 3, 6, 4, 3];
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the max key in your object, and then use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to make an array with a length equal to your max key. For `Array.from()` you can provide a mapping function which populates your array from the object:

```js
const obj = { 4: 7, 6: 8, 7: 6, 8: 8, 9: 3, 10: 6, 11: 4, 12: 3 };

const length = Math.max(...Object.keys(obj));
const res = Array.from({length}, (_, i) => obj[i+1] || 0);
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important;} /* ignore */
```

Alternatively, you can use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to assign your indexes object to an array object. You can use `Array.from()` with a mapping function to remove all `empty` values from your array and convert them to `0`s. Use [`.slice(1)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to remove the first item in your array:

```js
const obj = { 4: 7, 6: 8, 7: 6, 8: 8, 9: 3, 10: 6, 11: 4, 12: 3 };
const res = Array.from(Object.assign([], obj), n => n || 0).slice(1);
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important;} /* ignore */
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this online: https://runkit.com/embed/4uzqd6x6b1v8

```
let keys = Object.keys(obj);
let maxIndex = Math.max(...keys);
let output = [];
[...Array(maxIndex + 1).keys()].forEach( i => 
    output.push(keys.includes("" + i)? obj[i] : 0) 
});
```

Comment: that works. I didn’t quite understand how this line [...Array(maxIndex + 1).keys()] works. Could you explain to me a bit more details? Thanks for your help.

Comment: [...Array(maxIndex + 1).keys()] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], just try it in the runkit url to see the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using `Array.prototype.map`. More about [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var obj = {
  4: 7,
  6: 8,
  7: 6,
  8: 8,
  9: 3,
  10: 6,
  11: 4,
  12: 3
};
let a = [];
Object.keys(obj).map(val => a[val-1] = obj[val]);
a = Array.from(a, i => i || 0);
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [fill()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) methods:

```
const obj = {
  4: 7,
  6: 8,
  7: 6,
  8: 8,
  9: 3,
  10: 6,
  11: 4,
  12: 3
};

const output = new Array(12).fill(0).map( (cur, index) => obj[index + 1] || cur)
```

Explanation:

1. Create a new array with 12 elements in it
2. Fill it with 0s
3. `map` - for each element in the array, either take the value from the `obj` using `index + 1` (like you said - your object has the keys 1-based, not 0-based)
4. or if those keys don't exist, just return the original (which is 0)